# why does packer build is showing no such file or directory while trying to build image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, devops, packer

I have following packer script for building image:

```
 {
            "variables":
            {
            "aws_access_key": "",
            "aws_secret_key": "",
            "aws_region": "us-east-2",
            "version": "",
            "revision": "0",
            "instance_type": "t3.xlarge",
            "image_name" : "{{ env `IMAGE_NAME` }}"
            },
            "builders":{
                "type": "amazon-ebs",
                "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
                "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
                "region": "{{user `aws_region`}}",
                "instance_type": "{{user `instance_type`}}",
                "source_ami": "ami-09e1c6dd3bd60cf2e",
                "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
                "ami_name":"honebuild {{ isotime | clean_ami_name }"
            },
            "Provioners":[
                {
                "type":"shell",
                "script":"scripts/ssh_agent.sh"
                },
                {
                "type":"ansible",
                "playbook_dir":"./ansible",
                "playbook_file":"honeygram.yml"

                }

            ]



        }
```

After running the command packer build image.json. it is giving following error:

```
Failed to parse template: open packer.json: no such file or directory.
```

I am on the script directory.

Need help

Comment: What's the exact name of the above json file? And what's the exact command you run?

Comment: And what's the output of `packer version`.

Comment: my packer file name is image.json and packer version is 1.0.0. And I am running following command :   "packer build image.json". Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

From what you have posted it appears your issue is with your provisioners section.

You have:

```
"Provioners"
```

It should be:

```
"provisioners"
```

Comment: Yes thanks. there is some problem in packer version also. Thanks